# MySql Database migration

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

We have a large MySql table having around 400 million records, it is running on google cloud sql version 1 (MySql version 5.5).

Now google has come up with the new version of cloud sql (MySql version 5.6) ,so we want to migrate our database into this new sql version.This new version is available only on new instance. That means version 1 is on machine 1 and version 2 is on machine 2.

In this process we also made few schema changes, please check the following.

**Old Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE page_views_old (
  domain varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  guid varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  sid varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  ip varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  is_new varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  ref varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  stats_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  country varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  region varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  city_lat_long varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

**New schema**

```
CREATE TABLE page_views_new (
  domain varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  guid binary(16) NOT NULL,
  sid binary(16) NOT NULL,
  url varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  ip varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  is_new tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  ref varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  stats_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  country char(2) NOT NULL,
  region varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  city_lat_long varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

As mentioned above we changed datatype varchar to binary, varchar to varbinary, varchar to tinyint, ip to binary and others. So my question is what is best way to load this database into new instance. I didn't mention here we need to add few indexes also.

My approach for this problem

1.Take a dump of complete Database.

2.Import into new instance.

3.Modify columns one by one using alter table statements.

4.Make it live.

Can you guys please specify is there any issue with this approach and suggest me best approaches. Please mention if any issues with schema also.

Thanks

Comment: If you can tolerate the downtime of freezing your original database, this sounds like a good idea to me. Note that you can't go from varchar->varbinary using an alter table statement (some web searches should surface methods using temp columns and CAST functions).

Comment: @cflewis Thanks for your comment. Regarding varchar to varbinary conversion I opened a separate thread please check and reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149055/mysql-update-existing-varchar-column-ip-address-values-to-binary