# MYSQL-Update Existing Varchar column IP address values to Binary

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database with IP address stored as `varchar(20)`. To improve performance, I want to convert them to `varbinary(16)`. To support both ipv4 and ipv6 we stick to this datatype.

I choosed `varbinary(16)` over `binary(16)` because most of the values are ipv4.

I'm using `inet6_aton()` to convert into `binary`.

To modify datatype I'm doing following steps

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN ip VARBINARY(36) NOT NULL;

UPDATE table_name SET ip = INET6_ATON(ip));

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN ip VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL;
```

Are these datatype and conversion steps are correct? Are there any other problems?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it and see it if does what you need? Why ask here if you can do this yourself?

Comment: @Mjh It's working for me . I'm just asking are steps correct ??